# Disable multitouch in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I use Stage and Actors in my project. Can I disable and enable multitouch in runtime?
I'm using libgdx 0.9.7.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: Why would you ever need to disable multi-touch? It's up to your input handlers to accept which touches do what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Add an InputMultiplexer, add a custom InputProcessor that returns false in the touch methods if the pointer index > 0. Then add the Stage to the input multiplexer. That way, the first input processor will swallow all events of second/third/... touches.

From [libgdx forum](http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=9134&p=41331#p41331).

Comment: The idea is correct but it must return `true` instead of `false` if the `pointer > 0` to indicate the input has been processed and it's swallowed.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
actor.clearListeners();
```

when you detect the input in any of your image/actor then in its touchdown method
you can use this line of code...

Answer (score 0):

Set this as the first InputProcessor

```
public class SingleTouchInputProcessor extends InputAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return pointer > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return pointer > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return pointer > 0;
    }
}
```